# qemu set different dynamic ip address for each machine

Tags: debian, linux-networking, ip, libvirt, qemu

I need to run about 7 virtual machines via qemu at the same time. The problem is that they all have the same public IP address as the host. Is there any way to give them different ip addresses? host and guest system is debian.

I searched the Internet for solutions to this problem, but none came up

Comment: as i can clearly see that you may ask a enduser question inhere, I suggests that you flag your question for movement to superuser.com where it might be on topic. And short info, yes it is possible to get a VM a different IP.

Comment: Please edit your question to add guest and host network configuration, network diagram including the next hop to the internet, and the prefix you plan to address these out of.  Multiple public IP addresses without spending a lot may imply an IPv6 implementation.